# Could not navigate to another page react native

Tags: react-native, react-hooks, react-navigation

Hi guys sorry for the trouble . I am having this error

> TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'navigation.navigate')

Here's my code

```
const HomeScreen = ({navigation}) => {

  return(
     <View>
         <FlatList
              horizontal
              contentContainerStyle={{paddingHorizontal: 30}}
              data={userBookingData}
              keyExtractor={(item) => item.id} 
              renderItem={({item}) => <NewOrderPopUp navigation={navigation} {...item}/>} />                     
      </View>
  );

}
```

```
function NewOrderPopUp({navigation, .....})
{
  return(
    <Pressable onPress={()=> navigation.navigate('../../screens/AcceptedBookingScreen/AcceptedBookingScreen')}>
  );

}

export default NewOrderPopUp;
```

my package

```
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.2",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.0.6",
```

Help someone . Thank you.

#edit#

In my app.js

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';

// Import Navigators from React Navigation
import {NavigationContainer} from '@react-navigation/native';
import {createStackNavigator} from '@react-navigation/stack';
// Import Screens
import HomeScreen from './src/screens/HomeScreen';
import AcceptedBookingScreen from './src/screens/AcceptedBookingScreen/AcceptedBookingScreen';

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

  const App = () => {
    return (
      <NavigationContainer>
        <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="HomeScreen">
          <Stack.Screen
            name="HomeScreen"
            component={HomeScreen}
            options={{headerShown: false}}
          />
          <Stack.Screen
            name="AcceptedBookingScreen"
            component={AcceptedBookingScreen}
            options={{headerShown: false}}
          />
        </Stack.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
    );
  };

export default App;
```

but now I've got this error

> Error: Unable to resolve module react-native-safe-area-context from C:\Users\XXXXXXXXXXX\XXXXX\node_modules@react-navigation\stack\src\views\Header\Header.tsx: react-native-safe-area-context could not be found within the project or in these directories:
> node_modules@react-navigation\stack\node_modules
> node_modules

Comment: did you try like this: <Pressable onPress={()=> navigation.navigate('AcceptedBookingScreen')}> and in your router in need to specify that route

Comment: you should install react-native-safe-area-context see here https://reactnavigation.org/docs/getting-started/#installing-dependencies-into-a-bare-react-native-project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to try like this:

```
<Pressable onPress={()=> navigation.navigate('AcceptedBookingScreen')}>
```

and in your router in need to specify that route

example to use:

```
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';

function NotificationsScreen() {
const navigation = useNavigation(); 
return(
<Button
        onPress={() => navigation.navigate('AcceptedBookingScreen')}
        title="Go to notifications"
      />
);
}
```

you can create a routers in the app.js (Main)

```
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <NavigationContainer>
        <Stack.Navigator>
          <Stack.Screen
            name="AcceptedBookingScreen"
            component={AcceptedBookingScreen}
          />
        </Stack.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: this won't do because `Error: Couldn't find a navigation object. Is your component inside NavigationContainer` I am not inside a navigationcontainer

Comment: i've edited my question kindly take a look please .. thank you